# Selecting data from a certain date frame

Tags: php, sql

I've had many issues trying to find the problem to no hope.

I have a **user stats page** where it shows their all-time stats but would like to add a weekly and monthly stat page. Using **SQL** or **PHP** is there a way to get the total number from Monday to Friday. It needs to be from Monday to Sunday then resets the count back to 0 on Sunday. Selecting from one date range to another won't work because it'll have to change dynamically or is that not possible?

I want the results to be like this:
[image]

Table structure as shown: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIbEK.jpg

if you could help it would be much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and the tag for the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have provided an example of the outcome and tagged my database engine. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with Table structure with sample and output data.

Comment: @TanjimRahman Done. Is that enough test data? It gives a rough idea what to expect.